# MathJax not rendering in review box in FF4

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

Since I upgraded to Firefox 4.0, I've tried to ask two questions on the main page, but the functions aren't rendering in the review panel.  Since that feature is essential to making sure my question is formatted correctly, I'm forced to fly blind.

What is the basis behind this bug?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I do as well, so it's most likely not a fluke.

Comment: I guess you mean the _preview_ panel for questions and answers? It seems that Geoff talks about _review_ diffs in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a [similar question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1886/242), I too have this problem in all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) on XP SP3 on various computers. I find it quite difficult to compose answers *blindly* without any MathJax rendering. It's rather disappointing the the SE folks are not responding more quickly to this recently-introduced serious bug.

**Note to all:** if MathJax rendering is working in your Q&A preview windows, could you please leave a comment here describing your config. Perhaps we can employ such to help to troubleshoot the problem on our own.

Comment: Note: the problem described above was fixed a day or two after I posted the above.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: the `Ask Question` page is still sourcing `/content/js/third-party/math-tex.js` to load MathJax dynamically. But `math-tex.js` no longer exists (or doesn't load or is empty or...)

The other pages on math.stackexchange.com now source MathJax.js statically, so it's basically guaranteed to load.

EDIT: So I expect this issue is occurring in all browsers

Comment: As I said in my question, it happens in Chrome, Firefox and IE for me so its unlikely to be browser dependent.